# React+inline style + external js object - Image not showing

Tags: reactjs, image, inline, jsx

I'm new to react, and have been learning it through video tutorials, but I've gotten stuck on one part. I'm making a real estate listing site with react, and the search results are generated from a JS object. All the data is loading fine from the object (address, city, etc...), except the images.

The HTML line, in the listing component, looks like this:

```
<div className="listing-img" style={{background: 'url("${listing.image}") no-repeat center center'}}>
```

I'm pretty sure that is correct because when I replace the {listing.image} with an image url, it loads fine.

The object looks like this:

```
{
    address: '5500 Young Ave.',
    city: 'Portland',
    state:'OR',
    rooms:4,
    price:340000,
    floorSpace:3500,
    extras: [
        'elevator'
    ],
    homeType: 'apartment',
    image: 'https://image1.apartmentfinder.com/i2/Uh7pU-5z2gxB-ly2VsPGufzUCh0zPkDZH1YOZKjU6u8/110/cielo-apartments-charlotte-nc-saltwater-pool-and-courtyard.jpg'
},
```

Is something formatted wrong, or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can use template literals to apply url to background but what you are doing is you are not actually adding image value to url ${} this works only within template literals but not with strings

```
    <div className="listing-img" style={{background: {`url(${listing.image}) no-repeat center center`}}}>
```

Comment: Explaining what you changed and why is more helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Think-Twice.

Your response lead me to look up template literals, where I found out that I was using apostrophes (or single quotes) instead of back-ticks

' and ` do look pretty similar.

proper line is:

```
  <div className="listing-img" style={{background: `url("${listing.image}") no-repeat center center`}}>
```